# Word for someone who embraces change

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been futilely searching around for a word for someone who readily embraces change, or, is enthusiastic about it. I thought about an antonym for metathesiophobic, which is fear of change, but I couldn't even find anything for that. "Metathesiophilia" doesn't seem to be a word. Any suggestions?

Comment: Someone who embraces change is a *panhandler*.

Comment: Could you supply a sample sentence in which the proposed word would fit ? I am unclear as to what part of speech you want.

Comment: @HotLicks Nice. I hadn't thought of that usage.

Comment: @NigelJ Just a singular noun. I don't have a sentence for it. It's going in an infographic.

Comment: @HotLicks The only definitions that I can find for *panhandler*  say that it means a beggar. Is this a very specific AmE usage?

Comment: @Mick - Yes, and a panhandler embraces "change" (coins from your pocket).

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, dear! That's terrible. [groan]

Comment: @Mick - You haven't heard the worst of it!

Comment: This is a good example of problems with an swr without an example sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, **progressive** is actually the word you're looking for. A person who is progressive is one who favors change or innovation. Just look it up in any online dictionary if don't believe me. And right under the definition, there is a list of synonyms. Among them you will find terms such as **modernistic** and **progressivist** that might work for you just as well.

Comment: The OLD has this list for synonyms for progressive: innovator, reformer, reformist, liberal, libertarian, progressivist, progressionist, leftist, left-winger.  This answer is misleading.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm talking about. Take your pick.